# Is it possible to run an independent application inside a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, remote-access, remote-desktop

I need to control an independent application using a WinForms host application as if the other application were running on a Remote Desktop and my newly developed host application was the Remote Desktop host. The CodeProject article [Remote Desktop using C#.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET) is inspiring that the likelihood that my task is possible is not zero. It explains how to use the “Microsoft Terminal Services Control Type Library”, or `MSTSCLib.dll` to do this.

Howevere, I do not want to connect to a remote desktop. If anything, I want to connect to a second desktop on the same machine if that is necessary to independently run the hosted application, or something similar. Is this at all possible with `MSTSCLib`? If so, what aspects do I need to look at to further develop a design for this?

**IMPORTANT NOTICE:** The constraint of not having access to the code of the external program no longer exists. The 'guest' programs will be only from a range of specially defined programs.

Comment: You mean you want to embed their UI inside yours? WIthout their cooperation, this is not simple.  (and it's completely unrelated to TS; you need Windows API methods to reparent windows)

Comment: short answer no, long answer, everything is possible ...

Comment: @Slaks: That's why ProfK wants to "be a TS client on localhost" instead of reparenting windows: Because TS *can* be done without the cooperation of the "hosted" UI (and usually is).

Comment: you want to be able to open other applications in your own application.Right?

Comment: The illusion is complete when you get all the support calls for the bugs in the program you wrap.  You can typically monkey with SetParent(), Windows has appcompat for Windows 3.x programs where this was fully supported.  To what degree this still works for a program that's never seen that version of Windows is something you'll find out the hard way.

Comment: @ArashAtaAfarin Right!

Comment: @HansPassant The illusion is not mine, nor illusion, but a possible requirement of a very large rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

One Of My Friend Did this Work Sometimes Ago !

You Should Do Something Like This :

first import system DLLs :

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowLongA", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern long SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int nIndex, long dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);
```

Now declare a Timer And Follow these Codes :

```
    private const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
    private const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
    Process p;
 /*Closing Is Timer*/
        private void Closing_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            p.Refresh();
            string a = p.ProcessName;              
                SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
                SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
              MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, true);


    }
  void run(string add)
    {
        string addres = add;

        try
        {
            p = Process.Start(addres);
            Thread.Sleep(500); // Allow the process to open it's window
            SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle);
            SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
            MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, true);


        }
        catch
        {
            Closeing.Enabled = false;
            MessageBox.Show(addres + "\n" + "Not Found", "Error",
          MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.RtlReading);
            Environment.Exit(0);

        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Closeing.Enabled = true;
        run(@textBox1.Text); 
    }
```

Input Parameter Of Run Method Is the path of program that use want to run in your Application

Hope This Help! :)