# Disabling GUI features of elevated windows program

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, user-interface, windows-10

I wish to make it so that when a user of my program does a certain action (such as clicking on a button that is in my program's WinForm), the Windows On-Screen Keyboard (osk.exe) launches, but the caveat is that I want the On-Screen Keyboard to launch with a title bar that is disabled or removed—for example, disabling the Minimize button and the Exit/Close button.

My question is if anyone knows of a safe way to do this.

My reasoning is this: I want the windows on-screen keyboard to automatically come up during parts of my program, but we all know Murphy's law: Anything that can go wrong, will go wrong. **I don't want the user to be able to easily exit out of the OSK via its GUI half-way through typing.** The underlying program itself will know when to close/hide the osk.

I have tried searching for questions with similar problems, and the best that I found was the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142491/setwindowpos-returns-access-denied), where the question wasn't really answered, but one of the comments says

> If you want to avoid the access denied error, you'll need to elevate your process.

I know how to disable the Maximize/Exit/TitleBar/TitleMenu parts of the GUI myself, through previous C# SO questions (thank you!). But the problem is when the process is "[auto-elevated](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.07.uac.aspx)" when started. A normal user then doesn't have a way to edit the GUI without themselves being "elevated". And elevation seems to be an all-or-nothing deal; you're either an Administrator, or you're not. **Horrible for security if the end user has to run as Administrator!**

So I'm pleading for some safe solutions to this: Some way to be able to have a non-admin user be able to see and use an On-Screen Keyboard that doesn't have the Exit or Minimize button enabled. Perhaps there is a way to force another user, that the end-user doesn't have access to, to start and modify the OSK, so that the end-user themselves doesn't have to be privileged. Or a way to escalate the end-user just to have permission for this one specific process. 
*Are privileges like this really all-or-nothing deals?*

**Additional information:** Here are some links to people explaining how to disable certain parts of the GUI of a windows process.

- [remove components such as the Menu Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832828/how-to-remove-the-menubar-of-an-application-using-windows-api) of a GUI process.
- [Run an independent application inside a winforms application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337463/is-it-possible-to-run-an-independent-application-inside-a-winforms-application).
  For example, here is how you would get rid of the border of a notepad process and embed into a windows form:
      [DllImport("user32.dll")]
      static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);

  ```
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, bool repaint);

  private const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
  private const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
  private const int WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x01000000;

  private static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
  private const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
  private const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
  private const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;

  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
  public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);


  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad");

      p.WaitForInputIdle();
      if (p.MainWindowHandle == null)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(this, "hello", "Error");
      }
      SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, this.Handle);
      SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);

      MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, this.Width, this.Height, true);
  }
  ```

This works fine for a program that doesn't require elevation to use. But programs like the On-Screen keyboard, or MMC snap-ins, will give a non-administrative users Access Denied (5) errors when they attempt to use P/Invoke functions on the window, such as SetWindowPos.